# This sed end-case doesn't make sense, and I don't know why

Tags: linux, sed

I found the following `sed` end-case doesn't make sense, but I don't know why, and I cannot simplify it any further.

Basically I want to change one line and delete a range of lines, like this:

```sh
$ seq 9 | sed '/3/s/$/==/; /4/,/6/d;'
1
2
3==
7
8
9
```

However, when it comes to the following actual code, that I want to change one line and delete a range of lines, it doesn't work for me any more (if I uncomment the first command):

```sh
$ cat ./grub2clean.why-0.sed
#/menuentry/{ s/^/\n/; s/--\(class\|id\) .*$/\{/ };

# WHY?!
/Ubuntu/s/Ubuntu/UUUU/;
/^submenu /,/^}/d;
/UUUU/s/UUUU/!Ubuntu/;
```

I am running:

`sed -f ./grub2clean.why-0.sed grub.test.cfg`

if I un-comment the first command, the delete-a-range-of-lines command, which is in the middle of two working substitutions, no longer works any more.

This is so~~~~ strange and I don't know why.

Please, somebody help PLEASE!

The `grub.test.cfg` file is:

```
more here
menuentry 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/sda3)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt3'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic root=UUID=dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1 ro net.ifnames=0
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-33-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (20.04) (on /dev/sda3)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic--dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic root=UUID=dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1 ro net.ifnames=0
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-33-generic
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-33-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda3)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic-root=UUID=dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1 ro recovery nomodeset-dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt3'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1
                fi
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-33-generic root=UUID=dcf03c24-3d0d-4581-be1d-67b90f92a2c1 ro recovery nomodeset
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-33-generic
        }
}

menuentry 'Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/sda7)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux -
-class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-db9e32bf-a209
-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=
hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
        fi
        linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda7
        initrd /initrd.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/sda7)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652' {
        menuentry 'Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/sda7)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz--db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt7'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
                fi
                linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda7
                initrd /initrd.img
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/sda7)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz--db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt7'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
                fi
                linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda7
                initrd /initrd.img
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/sda7)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz--db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt7'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
                fi
                linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda7
                initrd /initrd.img.old
        }
        menuentry 'Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/sda7)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/vmlinuz.old--db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,gpt7'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt7 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt7  db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root db9e32bf-a209-453f-9eb9-82123fc46652
                fi
                linux /vmlinuz.old root=/dev/sda7
                initrd /initrd.img.old
        }
}

more here
```

Tested under both of the following two OSs,

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Release:        10.10
Codename:       buster
```

and

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
...

$ apt-cache policy sed
sed:
  Installed: 4.7-1
  Candidate: 4.7-1
  Version table:
 *** 4.7-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first sed command, you look for any line containing `menuentry` and stick a newline in as the first character of that line.

Then in the delete command, the range varies from a line starting with `submenu` to one starting with a closing brace.

When the script puts a newline in the first character of any line containing `menuentry` it also puts one as the first character of the lines starting with `submenu` because those lines also contain `menuentry` in the `$menuentry_id_option` bit.

So after the first sed command, there aren't any lines starting with `submenu` - all those lines start with a newline now.

So either your first sed command should match only lines that start with `menuentry` with optional leading whitespace, or the delete command should look for lines that start with a newline followed by `submenu`.

Comment: OMG, I've been banging my head on the wall for over an hours but still clueless. Thanks a lot, you've saved my day!!